# Erro ao definir uma constante

Tags: php, php-7, constantes

Estou recebendo o seguinte erro no meu código, e não estou conseguindo descobrir o motivo.

```
Got error 'PHP message: PHP Warning: Constants may only evaluate to scalar values in config.php on line 85
```

Nas linhas de 81 a 85 eu tenho o seguinte:

```
define("DATA_CONFIG",[
   "master_id" => $dados_config->sistema_master_id,
   "sis_url" => $dados_config->sistema_url,
   "api_key" => base64_decode($dados_config->sistema_key)
]);
```

Na 85 tenho o fechamento, mas na 84 tenho a linha a seguir, há algum problema usar o `base64_decode` em uma constante? Ou fazer essa conversão onde estou fazendo pode causar algum problema?

```
"api_key" => base64_decode($dados_config->sistema_key)
```

Comment: Em PHP até 5.6, constantes não podem conter arrays.

Comment: Estou usando 7.2

Comment: Tem certeza? Nessa versão essa mensagem de erro não deveria aparecer.